# Laravel Route::get() function and parameter confusing

Tags: laravel-4

Hello everyone I just installed laravel4 and spend two days trying to make the first step. Now I made it but I'm confused about the Route::get() function and his paremeters.

I installe laravel directly in

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/laravel
```

then follow tutorial to create file

```
userform.php
```

into app/views, then add following codes into routes.php

```
Route::get('userform', function()
{
return View::make('userform');
});
```

. Then I go to

```
/localhost/laravel/public
```

to see welcome page, and

```
/localhost/laravel/public/userform
```

to see the form defined in the view/userform.php.

Q1: According to chrome dev tools, i see in the html page, the form action is

```
http://localhost/laravel/public/userform
```

but there is nothing under public but

```
index.php, favicon.ico packages robots.txt
```

Q2: for

```
Route::get('userform', function()
{
    return View::make('userform');
});
```

what is the first "userform" represent?? according the official tutorial, it's supposed to be url, but what is the former part?
for this line

```
return View::make('userform')
```

I guess "userform" referes to the file /app/views/userform.php, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.htaccess` file in the public directory is responsible for funnelling all incoming requests through the `index.php` file. This allows Laravel to grab the URI and match it to the route you defined and eventually return to you the view you made.

So you request **localhost/laravel/public/userform**, the request is funnelled through **index.php** and Laravel is booted. Laravel picks off the **userform** part of the URI and matches it against your defined routes. It finds the route you defined and fires it and returns the response.

You're spot on with what you were thinking with your second question as well. When you call `View::make` the first argument is the name of the view you want to "make". If you named your view `app/views/forms/user.php` then you would return it like so in your route:

```
return View::make('forms.user');
```

Or you could use a slash:

```
return View::make('forms/user');
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I got important information from your answer and test it and I understand it better. So I just need to match the "/localhost/laravel/public/ **name** " with Route::get('**name**', function()), that's all.